# Adding opion to form label

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have form declared like this:

```
field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices = STATES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, label_suffix= "(%d)" % id)
```

let say STATES is decladed as

```
STATES = [(0, 'foo'), (1, 'bar')]
```

And I want to acheve labels that looks like this:

foo (0)
bar (1)

id should be option value (I'll call func there, so it has to be declared in form)
Any way to make it work?
Tyvm in advance

Michał

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to declare it in the states variable:

```
STATES = [(0, 'foo (0)'), (1, 'bar (1)')]
```

Now way around that unless you're pulling it in from a States Model, in which case you'd want a ModelChoiceField and a **unicode**(self) function on your States Model which returns something like:

```
return self.name + (' (%i)' % self.id)
```

Comment: Its not exacly what I wanted, but it gave me idea how to get this;) STATES arent model, so I cant declare __unicode__, but I can redefine states to add things I want to label, and use this instead of original as choices. Thanks!